# Is there a faster way to git-svn clone a wordpress plugin from the subversion repository?

Tags: svn, git, plugin-repository

When cloning a SVN repo with git-svn it searches laboriously through every revision for changes that are relevant (at least as I understand it).  Is there anyway to make this process quicker?

I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747075/how-to-git-svn-clone-the-last-n-revisions-from-a-subversion-repository that suggests it is possible to limit the number of revisions, just need to figure out how far back to go and how to find that number

Comment: If you are cloning , no, but why would you keep cloning the same repo?

Comment: Since it's the WP Plugin repo I'm not cloning the whole repo, I'm just cloning 10 plugins I want to track in Git.  It seems each one needs to go through 300,000+ revisions (see note I just added that might be the gateway to an answer)

Comment: Oh right, that is crazy. One day maybe wordpress will move to git or mercurial or any DRC for that matter. I don't think it would be very feasible to clone 10K + plugins to github, at least without asking them nicely.

Answer (score 9):

Yep, you can pass the initial revision from which to start scanning:

```
git svn clone -s -r387893 http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your-plugin/
```

You can hunt down that revision by using this command:

```
svn log http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/your-plugin/
```

The last line shows the earliest revision.

Source:

http://teleogistic.net/2011/05/revisiting-git-github-and-the-wordpress-org-plugin-repository/

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a good way to guess how many revisions back I should start?  I'd be happy with 12 months or something, but I'm really unfamiliar with svn and how I'd find that.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Scribu, I'm so much happier now.  I finally got everything I was tracking in SVN moved over to Git-SVN and it only took a few minute per plugin instead of hours per plugin it took before.